# typescript compiler ignoring define/import in 1 file

Tags: typescript

I'm suddenly having a very weird compile of one of my files.

comm.ts:

```
import document = require('./document/document');
import element = require('./document/elements/element');
import paragraph = require('./document/elements/paragraph');
import listBody = require('./document/list-body');
// ...
```

comm.js:

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
define(["require", "exports"], function(require, exports) {
// ...
```

What's with the extends and more important, why does the define not pull in the 4 imports? They are used in the code.

And the big problem is that now when I run I get the error:

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference 
comm.js, line 18 character 5

which is in the code listed above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What's with the extends

TypeScript generates it to assist with inheritance. ie. `class A extends B` will result in the extends function being added.

> why does the define not pull in the 4 imports? They are used in the code.

I don't believe they are used in the code. Ensure you have something like:

```
import listBody = require('./document/list-body');
var foo = listBody; // this will ensure code gen.
```

Your error `Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference comm.js is reflecting to this fact. You are trying to extend something that isn't loaded (is missing in the generated define) because TypeScript thinks it isn't needed at runtime.

**Local test**
I have verified that the code generated by TypeScript is correct if it notices an `extend`.

*foo.ts:*

```
class Foo{}
export = Foo;
```

*bar.ts:*

```
import Foo = require('./foo');
class Bar extends Foo{}
```

*compile:*
`tsc --module amd bar.ts`

Generated *bar.js*:

```
var __extends = this.__extends || function (d, b) {
    for (var p in b) if (b.hasOwnProperty(p)) d[p] = b[p];
    function __() { this.constructor = d; }
    __.prototype = b.prototype;
    d.prototype = new __();
};
define(["require", "exports", './foo'], function(require, exports, Foo) {
    var Bar = (function (_super) {
        __extends(Bar, _super);
        function Bar() {
            _super.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        return Bar;
    })(Foo);
});
```

Comment: The import's are needed, but only to define types. So I'm guessing that for type definitions, that's needed at compile time but not run time. However, the __extends function still throws an exception. On entry b is undefined and d is "function RunProperties" which is a class I have, but it is not referenced in this file anywhere.

Comment: How do I find out what the extends issue is? I've looked at the code carefully and all extends in this file are of classes & interfaces in this same file.

Comment: Are circular import's not allowed? I have a case where file1 imports file2 and file2 imports file1.

Comment: I found it - it required diving into the requireJS on the exception to the core cause. Which was I hadn't loaded collections.js before it was needed. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In  my case, it was because I had a `class Call` extending a `class Task`, and the files for both classes were in the same folder.  Which by itself isn't a problem, but Typescript/gulp compiles files within the same folder in order of file creation (modification?).  So `public class Call extends Task` in file *Call.ts* was getting compiled before `class Task` in file *Task.ts*, and so `Task` wasn't defined at the time it was needed. Hence the error "Unable to get property 'prototype' of undefined or null reference".

Slightly maddening was the fact that both of those classes have a parent class elsewhere, which has a grandparent class, and the runtime error was thrown on the grandparent. The grandparent's from another folder, in another module, and is used successfully in many, many places across the app.